# What is technical specs for iOS platform for a game?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I would like to know when a contractor ask you for a technical specs for iOS platform of a game, what's the description that you should give back to him?

Answer (score 1):

Usually technical specs for an iOS game should be something related to hardware generations. For eg:- game should support all devices from iPhone 3GS and above , should support iPad 2 and above etc , iPod touch 4th generation and above etc.

Answer (score 1):

### Set concrete and measurable specs for as much as possible.

**- List of supported device types and generations**

- iPhone
- iPod touch
- iPad

For the iPod touch **specifically** ask for guarantees regarding memory requirements. Even some high profile games can run out of memory on the iPod Touch. The developers usually use iPhones for development and don't bother with thorough testing, assuming the hardware is the same. But it has half the memory! Same for 1st gen iPad.

**- List of device versions**

iPod touch 2nd generation and iPhone 3G are quite old and slow, so I'd suggest setting iPhone 3GS as minimum. List all devices that you want to be supported.

**- iOS versions**

Example: it might be extra work to support iOS 4 and Game Center support will be disabled.

**- Language support**

If you plan on ever adding more languages, the game should be setup to support it from the start - localization strings, support loading different artwork and audio for each language etc.

**- Game Center integration**

**- Retina-grade artwork**

(As opposed to blurry/jagged upscaled versions of low resolution artwork.)

**- Support for iPhone 5's screen resolution**

It is taller, so artwork must be redone, game must be adjusted.

**- Performance**

As with the memory requirements, get specific guarantees. For example: startup time is x seconds from tapping icon to main menu on iPhone 4, framerate never falls below 30fps on iPhone 4 or averages to at least 40fps during a typical gameplay session. IPA package size [below 50MB](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/03/07/apple-boosts-over-the-air-app-store-download-limits-to-50-mb/). And of course: **no crashing**. You might ask them to integrate a crash reporter such as [this one](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/) or [this one](http://www.crittercism.com).

**- App store validation**

The deal is not done until it passes Apple's validation process.

**- Special requests**

Support for iCade and other 3rd party controllers, TV output, Airplay support etc.

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT** technical specifications for iOS platform games

**OS Specification**

- Minimum iOS (5.1 or 4.3 etc)

**Hardware Specifications**

- iPhone & iPod Touch (Retina, 3.5 inch, 4 inch)
- iPad (1, 2, New)

App/Game device Family

- iPhone
- iPad
- Universal

**GPU Specification**

- OpenGL ES (v1.1 or v2.0)

**Others**

- iPod touch 2nd generation and iPhone 3G are quite old and slow, and
  OpenGL ES v1.1 does not support those versions. So would you add / remove those as technical spec.
- Memory requirements
- IPA size issue

Answer (score 0):

just specify the target device and OS e.g

iPad1/iPad2/iPad3(Retina)/iPhone Retina including iPhone 5, iOS 6+